# ¿Cómo animar un valor numérico en un html con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

¡Hola buenas!

El caso es que en mi `HTML` tengo un texto con un número que es el valor del carrito, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando se añada un artículo nuevo y cambie el valor no cambie directamente sino que con `Javascript` el valor cambiado suba como en los juegos muy rápido en principio y más lento al final.

He hecho una función que se llama cada `100 ms` para actualizar el valor, pero lo actualiza de 1 en 1

```html
<text id='valor-cesta'> 2000 </text>

<script>
  //Variable global para guardar el intervalo
  var animInterval;

  function startAnim() {

    let obj = document.getElementById('valor-cesta');
    animInterval = setInterval(animNumValue, 100, obj, 3000);
  }

  function animNumValue(num, newValue) {

    valor = num.innerHTML;
    intValue = parseInt(valor);

    if (intValue >= newValue) { //Si el valor ha superado el objetivo paro
      clearInterval(animInterval);
    } else { //Si el valor no ha superado el objetivo lo aumento
      valor++;
      num.innerHTML = valor;
    }
  }
  startAnim();
</script>
```

Comment: pero no entiendo, tu aqui no tienes ninguna animacion?

Comment: vale no es animacion, es como un contador que va incrementado, poco a poco

Comment: El valor cambia cada vez que se añade un elemento a la cesta, yo lo que quiero es que no cambie el valor directamente de golpe, si no que ocurra una especie de "animación" en la que el valor suba de mucho a poco

Answer (score 4):

Reduce el tiempo de *setInterval* e incrementa el valor de acuerdo a la diferencia. Agrega, modifica o quita comparaciones de diferencia, hasta que encuentres la opción que te agrade.

```html
<text id='valor-cesta'> 2000 </text>

<script>
  //Variable global para guardar el intervalo
  var animInterval;

  function startAnim() {

    let obj = document.getElementById('valor-cesta');
    animInterval = setInterval(animNumValue, 30, obj, 3000);
  }

  function animNumValue(num, newValue) {

    let valor = parseInt(num.innerText);
    if (valor >= newValue) {
      //Si el valor ha superado el objetivo paro
      clearInterval(animInterval);
    } else {
      //Si el valor no ha superado el objetivo lo aumento
      let diferencia = newValue - valor;
      // A mayor diferencia, mayor incremento
      if(diferencia > 225) {
          valor += 219; // Valores no exactos para ver cambios en contador
      } else if(diferencia > 100) {
          valor += 95;
      } else if(diferencia > 10) {
          valor += 6;
      } else {
          valor++;
      }
      num.innerText = valor;
    }
  }
  startAnim();
</script>
```

### Actualización

Otra opción es dividir la diferencia para buscar que la duración sea similar, independientemente de la cantidad a agregar:

```js
  //Variable global para guardar el intervalo
  var animInterval;

  function startAnim() {
    let obj = document.getElementById('valor-cesta');
    let sumar = parseInt(document.querySelector('#sumar').value);
    if(sumar > 0) {
        animInterval = setInterval(animNumValue, 30, obj, parseInt(obj.innerText) + sumar);
    }
  }

  function animNumValue(num, newValue) {

    let valor = parseInt(num.innerText);
    if (valor >= newValue) {
      //Si el valor ha superado el objetivo paro
      clearInterval(animInterval);
    } else {
      //Si el valor no ha superado el objetivo lo aumento
      let diferencia = newValue - valor;
      valor += Math.ceil(diferencia/3);

      num.innerText = valor;
    }
  }
document.querySelector('#agregar').addEventListener('click', startAnim);
```

```html
<text id="valor-cesta">2000</text><br>
<input type="number" id="sumar" value=""><br>
<button id="agregar">Agregar</button>
```

Comment: y cuando el valor sea mayor de 2000? o mas pequeño?

Comment: Por otro lado, hay veces que printa un valor superior al deseado, por las sumas no dinamicas

Comment: @Srsole, probé con 300 y funcionó bien. Por otra parte, la única forma de que supere el valor deseado es que pongas la suma mayor a la comparación.

Comment: desde mi punto de vista son hard codes, y no lo veo funcional.

Comment: ¿@Srsole, cómo lo ves ahora?

Comment: ahora lo veo genial, independientemente del valor siempre sera de la misma duracion  al animacio, programado  y nade de hard codes! ;) +1

Answer (score -1):

Prueba asi:

```
//Variable global para guardar el intervalo
var animInterval;

function startAnim(){

  let obj = document.getElementById('valor-cesta');
  var x = parseInt(obj.innerHTML/3000);
  animInterval = setInterval(function(){
                    animNumValue();
                 },x);
}

function animNumValue(){

  var valor = document.getElementById('valor-cesta');
  var intValue = parseInt(valor);
  var newValue = parseInt(valor + 1)
  if(intValue >= newValue) { //Si el valor ha superado el objetivo paro
    clearInterval(animInterval);
  }else{//Si el valor no ha superado el objetivo lo aumento
    valor++;
    num.innerHTML = valor;
  }
}
```

Básicamente lo que pasa es que tu quieres que en 3000 milis se pare el contador, entonces hay que dividir el total de items en el carrito entre el tiempo total que quieres que dure la 'animación'
De hay sale la variable `x`

---

Esta forma de hacerlo es dinámica, y el contador siempre tardara lo mismo, 3 segundos, parándose en el valor deseado.

Comment: No funciona, porque no ejecutas `startAnim()` y no envías parámetros a `animValue()`, aparte, si los envías, _newValue_ siempre será menor que el valor inicial.

Comment: @Triby Hola compañero, antes que nada es solo una parte del codigo, donde llamar al metodo es cosa suya.

Comment: @Triby Lo otro a hora lo edito, no es necesario tener newvalue

Comment: En el código de la pregunta aparece esa línea y es conveniente crear un fragmento de código para que se pueda probar y verificar que la respuesta es adecuada. Después de la edición, tu código quedó prácticamente igual que la pregunta, sumando de uno en en uno. Por cierto, yo solo acostumbro comentar, el -1 no es mío :-)

Comment: @Triby suma de 1 en 1, pero a diferente velocidad, si son 10.000 se cargara en 3 segundos, es decir a 3.333,33 números por segundo, si son 2000 como el ejemplo pues 666,7 por segundo, de tu manera puedes estar siglos, y por tiempo indefinido y no lo veo bien, pues una animacion tiene inicio y tenemos que saber el fin (x segundos) es mi opinion.